# How to enable a MVVM-disabled Kendo DropDownList?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mvvm

```html
<select id="ddlFailureCategory" class="full-width"
        required="required"
        data-required-msg="@(String.Format(Resources.Error.RequiredField, Resources.Wording.FailureCategory))"
        data-bind="source: DataSource.FailureCategoryDropDown, value: ViewModel.FailureCategory, disabled: Layout.isDisabled"
        data-role="dropdownlist"
        data-value-primitive="true"
        data-value-field="Code"
        data-text-field="Description">
</select>
```

I have a dropdownlist which is initialized using MVVM binding, and it is disabled as expected.

Now under some situations, I want to enable this dropdownlist programmactically in some events fired by other controls.

In that event handler, I call this line:

`$("#ddlFailureCategory").data("kendoDropDownList").enable(true);`

which is as written in the API [Kendo DropDownlist API: enable](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox#methods-enable)

However it is not working, the dropdownlist is still being disabled, while there is NO any JavaScript errors.

I tried to type the JavaScript in Chrome developer console directly as well, the element is found,  `.data()` & `.enable()` is called without any errors.

What is wrong in my approach and how can I achieve the expected behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [@AndreiDragotoniu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958213/how-to-enable-a-mvvm-disabled-kendo-dropdownlist#37961254)'s answer, if `Layout` is your View-Model, you'll want to set `isDisabled` to `false`.

But to do that, you'll want to do it as **`Layout.set('isDisabled', false);`**, just assigning the value directly will not trigger the appropriate events for two-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

the disabled state of the dropdown is controlled by

```
Layout.isDisabled
```

so set it to false when the conditions you want are met.

```
Layout.isDisabled = false;
```

If you use MVVM then use MVVM, don't try to go around it in order to get what you need.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the problem...I set that to false as I want it to be disabled initially, but after that I want to enable it (but failed), and that is the problem...

Comment: @Shole, what Andrei is suggesting, is to keep using isDisabled. E.g. Disabled set to true, disables the drop down. Disabled set to false enables the drop down. Essentially enable and disable are 2 different attributes. That's the beauty of 2 way binding.